# PostgreSql PHP query #1: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error:

Tags: php, postgresql, search

I try to realize search from album where I set artist in form. I get variable from form 
and I make query. Successfully I get variable from the form.

```
$words = $_REQUEST['SQLfield'];
$tempquery =  "SELECT * FROM album WHERE to_tsvector(artist) @@ to_tsquery('$words')";
do_sql($tempquery);
```

When I search for example Jimi Hendrix the result is:

```
query #1: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error in tsquery: "Jimi Hendrix "
```

Comment: passing user provided variable directly into query, w/o any escaping is VERY BAD THING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used Full Text Search in PostgreSQL but after quick scanning [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-textsearch.html) I think that you should use `plainto_tsquery` function instead of `to_tsquery`, since `to_tsquery` expects something like `'jimi & hendrix'` when `plainto_tsquery` will accept phrases like `'Jimi Hendrix'`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I only changed to_tsquery to plainto_tsquery.